# Error in currency transfer

Tags: balances, tcurrency

I have currency configuration as follows

```
use frame_support::traits::{Currency};
```

and in frame config

```
type Currency: Currency<Self::AccountId>;
```

Then in an extrincis function, I am trying to do a transfer

```
<T as Config>::Currency::transfer(
                &who,
                &validators_account,
                transaction_fee,
                ExistenceRequirement::KeepAlive
)?;
```

This throws an error

```
     --> /home/dev/Desktop/projects/GIANT/pallets/provider/src/lib.rs:281:5
      |
  278 |             <T as Config>::Currency::transfer(
      |             --------------------------------- arguments to this function are incorrect
  ...
  281 |                 transaction_fee,
      |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found `u128`
      |
      = note: expected associated type `<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance`
                            found type `u128`
```

But when I explore tests for transfer function in the substrate it uses integer values

```
                assert_noop!(
                    <Balances as Currency<_>>::transfer(&1, &2, 3, AllowDeath),
                    Error::<$test, _>::LiquidityRestrictions
                );
```

This throws an error as well

```
            <T as Config>::Currency::transfer(
                &who,
                &validators_account,
                100,
                ExistenceRequirement::KeepAlive
            )?;
```

Error

```
            <T as Config>::Currency::transfer(
      |             --------------------------------- arguments to this function are incorrect
  ...
  281 |                 100,
      |                 ^^^ expected associated type, found integer
      |
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error is noting, the it expects an associated type `Balance`, not a concrete type.

While your runtime may use the u128 type, your pallet does not know that, and instead uses a generic type which you must take into account.

The easiest thing would be to `use sp_runtime::traits::UniqueSaturatedInto;`, then add `.unique_saturated_into()` to your value.

```rust
/// Just like `From` except that if the source value is too big to fit into the destination type
/// then it'll saturate the destination.
pub trait UniqueSaturatedFrom<T: Sized>: Sized {
    /// Convert from a value of `T` into an equivalent instance of `Self`.
    fn unique_saturated_from(t: T) -> Self;
}
```

So something like this compiles:

```rust
use sp_runtime::traits::UniqueSaturatedInto;
let source = T::Lookup::lookup(source)?;
let dest = T::Lookup::lookup(dest)?;
<Self as Currency<_>>::transfer(
    &source,
    &dest,
    100u128.unique_saturated_into(),
    ExistenceRequirement::AllowDeath,
)?;
```