# Collect some transfer fees before any transaction

Tags: transactions, fee, transfer, pallet-treasury

I want to collect some transfer fee besides base, weight, length fee before user makes a transaction.

Like if the base + weight + length fee = 0.1
And For every transaction I want to add additional 0.2 then total fee should become 0.3.

This 0.2 will go in treasury.

How can I implement this in substrate/parachain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the logic around the transaction fee pallet is wrapped into the trait `OnChargeTransaction`:

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_transaction_payment/trait.OnChargeTransaction.html

So you just need to implement this with the logic you want.

You can look at the implementation [`CurrencyAdapter`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_transaction_payment/struct.CurrencyAdapter.html) which is used in Polkadot to see how it can be implemented, and probably you can modify it to do what you want.

For example:

```rust
pub struct CustomCurrencyAdapter<C, OU>(PhantomData<(C, OU)>);

impl<T, C, OU> OnChargeTransaction<T> for CustomCurrencyAdapter<C, OU>
where
    T: Config,
    C: Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>,
    C::PositiveImbalance: Imbalance<
        <C as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance,
        Opposite = C::NegativeImbalance,
    >,
    C::NegativeImbalance: Imbalance<
        <C as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance,
        Opposite = C::PositiveImbalance,
    >,
    OU: OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalanceOf<C, T>>,
{
    type LiquidityInfo = Option<NegativeImbalanceOf<C, T>>;
    type Balance = <C as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;

    /// Withdraw the predicted fee from the transaction origin.
    ///
    /// Note: The `fee` already includes the `tip`.
    fn withdraw_fee(
        who: &T::AccountId,
        _call: &T::RuntimeCall,
        _info: &DispatchInfoOf<T::RuntimeCall>,
        fee: Self::Balance,
        tip: Self::Balance,
    ) -> Result<Self::LiquidityInfo, TransactionValidityError> {
        if fee.is_zero() {
            return Ok(None)
        }

        let withdraw_reason = if tip.is_zero() {
            WithdrawReasons::TRANSACTION_PAYMENT
        } else {
            WithdrawReasons::TRANSACTION_PAYMENT | WithdrawReasons::TIP
        };


//here--->
        let fee = fee + whatever_you_want;

        match C::withdraw(who, fee, withdraw_reason, ExistenceRequirement::KeepAlive) {
            Ok(imbalance) => Ok(Some(imbalance)),
            Err(_) => Err(InvalidTransaction::Payment.into()),
        }
    }

    /// Hand the fee and the tip over to the `[OnUnbalanced]` implementation.
    /// Since the predicted fee might have been too high, parts of the fee may
    /// be refunded.
    ///
    /// Note: The `corrected_fee` already includes the `tip`.
    fn correct_and_deposit_fee(
        who: &T::AccountId,
        _dispatch_info: &DispatchInfoOf<T::RuntimeCall>,
        _post_info: &PostDispatchInfoOf<T::RuntimeCall>,
        corrected_fee: Self::Balance,
        tip: Self::Balance,
        already_withdrawn: Self::LiquidityInfo,
    ) -> Result<(), TransactionValidityError> {
        if let Some(paid) = already_withdrawn {
            // Calculate how much refund we should return
            let refund_amount = paid.peek().saturating_sub(corrected_fee);
            // refund to the the account that paid the fees. If this fails, the
            // account might have dropped below the existential balance. In
            // that case we don't refund anything.
            let refund_imbalance = C::deposit_into_existing(who, refund_amount)
                .unwrap_or_else(|_| C::PositiveImbalance::zero());
            // merge the imbalance caused by paying the fees and refunding parts of it again.
            let adjusted_paid = paid
                .offset(refund_imbalance)
                .same()
                .map_err(|_| TransactionValidityError::Invalid(InvalidTransaction::Payment))?;
            // Call someone else to handle the imbalance (fee and tip separately)
            let (tip, fee) = adjusted_paid.split(tip);
            OU::on_unbalanceds(Some(fee).into_iter().chain(Some(tip)));
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Search `here--->` in the code above.

Comment: Hey @shawn thanks for the reply. But is there a way to do it without changing code in transaction payment pallet ? because I am using parity substrate repo directly to for transaction payment pallet. or are you saying that I should create a custom CustomCurrencyAdapter in my code and use that in my code?
Please correct If I am taking it in the wrong direction.
Thanks

Comment: This is an external trait implementation that you can plug into an unchanged transaction payment pallet.

Comment: Hey @shawn, I tried this but I am getting an error.
Can you please help?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> network-node/runtime/dev/src/impls.rs:68:25
     |
  68 |         let fee = fee + 3000;
     |                         ^^^^ expected associated type, found integer
     |
     = note: expected associated type `<C as hidden_include::traits::Currency<<T as SysConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance`
                           found type `{integer}`

What should I pass here? I want to add 0.3 to the overall fee

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you haven't resolved your last question asked after the above answer was accepted, Shawn's answer at [Error in currency transfer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3241/error-in-currency-transfer/3242#3242) should explain what is going on with your `expected associated type` issue and how to fix it.

I was unable to add this as a comment beneath your question unfortunately.